# Incrementing first part of custom field in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a very specific request for incrementing first part of custom field in Excel. The field has format `xx/aa/bb` where `aa` and `bb` are static values (no increment) and the `xx` is the value that should be incremented by 1.

So the values for example should be:

```
1/05/05  
2/05/05  
3/05/05  
4/05/05  
..  
211/05/05  
212/05/05  
..
```

How can I do this in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=ROW()&"/05/05"
```

and add an offset (+ or -) if desired.